# JavaFX Address Book updating contacts with same info (SQL)

Tags: java, sql, database, javafx

So I am finishing up an Address book in JavaFX. The user can add, edit, delete and view all the contacts that are stored in the database. However I have a small problem, if multiple records share one piece of information, when I edit something for one of them it updates it for everything. Here's an example:

Let's say there's three people in my DB (John, Charli, and another John)

And let's say all three people have different phone numbers. I want to update the first John's phone number. When I change it, it edits both John's phone number to the new value I entered.

This issue 100% has something to do with how I wrote my SQL for the update function. Here's what I have now.

```
  public void updateData(String column, String newValue, String id) throws SQLException {

    String updateQuery = "UPDATE contacts SET " + column + " = ? WHERE " + column + "= ? ";

    try {
      PreparedStatement psmt = DBConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(updateQuery);
      psmt.setString(1, newValue);
      psmt.setString(2, id);
      psmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

UpdateData is called by methods whose fields I want to change, like so.

```
  public void changePhoneNumberCellEvent(CellEditEvent editedCell) throws SQLException {
    Person person = table_contact.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String oldPhoneNumber = person.getPhone_number();
    person.setPhone_number(editedCell.getNewValue().toString());
    updateData("phone_number", editedCell.getNewValue().toString(), oldPhoneNumber);
  }
```

Now I know my SQL is breaking because it finds multiple of the same values in the first_name column for example? Is there a way I can edit this SQL so it only changes the info of person I want to change? I did some research and the DISTINCT keyword was brought up but I don't think that could help because 2 people could share the same first name/last name, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest that you always use a primary key in your database? It could be a combination of their first and last name. I like using a unique numerical key.

Comment: Use an integer or long as the unique ID. Update the appropriate column where id = someUniqueNumber.

Answer (score 2):

Always use a primary key as a unique identifier for the dataset. When updating, deleting you should then always use that unique identifier. Otherwise your queries will cause side effects. For example deleting multiple datasets that share the same data in a column.